# Transition animation gone when presenting a NavigationLink in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink

I have a List with NavigationLinks.

```
List {
    ForEach(items, id: \.id) { item in
        NavigationLink(destination: ItemView(), tag: item.id, selection: self.$viewModel.selectedItemId) {
            Text("Some text")
        }
    }
    .onDelete(perform: delete)
}
.id(UUID())
```

And a corresponding ViewModel which stores the selected item's id.

```
class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var selectedItemId: String? {
        didSet {
            if let itemId = selectedItemId {
                ...
            }
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

The problem is that when I use `NavigationLink(destination:tag:selection:)` the transition animation is gone - the child view pops up immediately. When I use `NavigationLink(destination:)` it works normally, but I can't use it because I need to perform some action when a NavigationLink is selected.

Why the transition animation is gone? Is this a problem with `NavigationLink(destination:tag:selection:)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out to be a problem with `.id(UUID())` at the end of the list. Removing it restores the transition animation:

```
List {
    ForEach(items, id: \.id) { item in
        NavigationLink(destination: ItemView(), tag: item.id, selection: self.$viewModel.selectedItemId) {
            Text("Some text")
        }
    }
    .onDelete(perform: delete)
}
//.id(UUID()) <- removed this line
```

I added this following this link [How to fix slow List updates in SwiftUI](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/articles/210/how-to-fix-slow-list-updates-in-swiftui). Looks like this hack messes up tags/selections when using `NavigationLink(destination:tag:selection:)`.

Answer (score 2):

You could put your action inside the NavigationLink. This should solve your animation problem:

```
List {
    ForEach(items, id: \.id) { item in
        NavigationLink(destination: ItemView(), isActive: $isActive, tag: item.id, selection: self.$viewModel.selectedItemId) {
            EmptyView()
        }
        Button(action: {
            // The action you wand to have done, when the View pops.
            print("Test")
            self.isActive = true
        }, label: {
            Text("Some text")
        })
    }
    .onDelete(perform: delete)
}
.id(UUID())
```

Comment: Thanks. I've upvoted your answer, although it's a workaround and not a direct solution.