# SwiftUI Reorder list dynamic sections from another view

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-list

I have a simple `List` with sections that are stored inside an `ObservableObject`. I'd like to reorder them from another view.

This is my code:

```
class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var sections = ["S1", "S2", "S3", "S4"]
    
    func move(from source: IndexSet, to destination: Int) {
        sections.move(fromOffsets: source, toOffset: destination)
    }
}
```

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel = ViewModel()
    @State var showOrderingView = false

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button("Reorder sections") {
                self.showOrderingView = true
            }
            list
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $showOrderingView) {
            OrderingView(viewModel: self.viewModel)
        }
    }

    var list: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(viewModel.sections, id: \.self) { section in
                Section(header: Text(section)) {
                    ForEach(0 ..< 3, id: \.self) { _ in
                        Text("Item")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
struct OrderingView: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: ViewModel

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                ForEach(viewModel.sections, id: \.self) { section in
                    Text(section)
                }
                .onMove(perform: viewModel.move)
            }
            .navigationBarItems(trailing: EditButton())
        }
    }
}
```

But in the `OrderingView` when trying to move sections I'm getting this error: *"Attempt to create two animations for cell"*. Likely it's because the order of the sections has changed.

How can I change the order of the sections?

Comment: With Xcode 12 / iOS 14 - no error, but does not work either.

Comment: @Asperi Do you know if I should somehow disable animations just for changing the order of the sections? Or maybe is there another way to do it?

Comment: No, the problem here is different. Just add `init() { print("created") }` for ViewModel and perform your scenario - you'll see. With `@StateObject` in SwiftUI 2.0 it is not better. You've got into very interesting SwiftUI bug. ))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem of this scenario is recreated many times `ViewModel`, so modifications made in sheet just lost. (The strange thing is that in SwiftUI 2.0 with StateObject these changes also lost and EditButton does not work at all.)

Anyway. It looks like here is a found workaround. The idea is to break interview dependency (binding) and work with pure data passing them explicitly into sheet and return them back explicitly from it.

Tested & worked with Xcode 12 / iOS 14, but I tried to avoid using SwiftUI 2.0 features.

```
class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var sections = ["S1", "S2", "S3", "S4"]

    func move(from source: IndexSet, to destination: Int) {
        sections.move(fromOffsets: source, toOffset: destination)
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel = ViewModel()
    @State var showOrderingView = false

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button("Reorder sections") {
                self.showOrderingView = true
            }

            list
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $showOrderingView) {
            OrderingView(sections: viewModel.sections) {
                self.viewModel.sections = $0
            }
        }
    }

    var list: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(viewModel.sections, id: \.self) { section in
                Section(header: Text(section)) {
                    ForEach(0 ..< 3, id: \.self) { _ in
                        Text("Item")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct OrderingView: View {
    @State private var sections: [String]
    let callback: ([String]) -> ()

    init(sections: [String], callback: @escaping ([String]) -> ())
    {
        self._sections = State(initialValue: sections)
        self.callback = callback
    }

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                ForEach(sections, id: \.self) { section in
                    Text(section)
                }
                .onMove {
                    self.sections.move(fromOffsets: $0, toOffset: $1)
                }
            }
            .navigationBarItems(trailing: EditButton())
        }
        .onDisappear {
            self.callback(self.sections)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I checked your code and your workaround looks better than mine. However, in iOS 13 it doesn't work - I'm still getting *"Attempt to create two animations for cell"* error. Thanks again for your help - I'll report a bug to Apple.

Answer (score 0):

**A possible workaround solution for SwiftUI 1.0**

I found a workaround to disable animations for the `List` by adding `.id(UUID())`:

```
var list: some View {
    List {
        ...
    }
    .id(UUID())
}
```

This, however, messes the transition animations for NavigationLinks created with `NavigationLink(destination:tag:selection:)`: [Transition animation gone when presenting a NavigationLink in SwiftUI](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61988298/8697793).

And all other animations (like `onDelete`) are missing as well.

The even more hacky solution is to disable list animations conditionally:

```
class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    ...
    @Published var isReorderingSections = false
    ...
}
```

```
struct OrderingView: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: ViewModel

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ...
        }
        .onAppear {
            self.viewModel.isReorderingSections = true
        }
        .onDisappear {
            self.viewModel.isReorderingSections = false
        }
    }
}
```

```
struct ContentView: View {
    ...
    var list: some View {
        List {
            ...
        }
        .id(viewModel.isReorderingSections ? UUID().hashValue : 1)
    }
}
```