# How to Re-Order List Sections SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swiftui

I want to re-order List sections in swift UI, I found a way to re-order the section but the data of each section doesn't get passed with it. I found the initial code from here [SwiftUI Reorder list dynamic sections from another view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62996572/swiftui-reorder-list-dynamic-sections-from-another-view) but I can't get the data to be passed when I move a section. Can anyone help?

```
import SwiftUI

class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var sections = ["NBA","NFL"]
    @State var NFLmodel = [Event]()
    @State var NBAmodel = [Event]()
    func move(from source: IndexSet, to destination: Int) {
        sections.move(fromOffsets: source, toOffset: destination)
        NBAmodel.move(fromOffsets: source, toOffset: destination)
        NFLmodel.move(fromOffsets: source, toOffset: destination)
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel = ViewModel()
    @State var showOrderingView = false
    @State var NFLmodel = [Event]()
    @State var NBAmodel = [Event]()

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button("Reorder sections") {
                self.showOrderingView = true
            }

            list
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $showOrderingView) {
            OrderingView(sections: viewModel.sections) {
                self.viewModel.sections = $0
                self.viewModel.NBAmodel = $0
                self.viewModel.NFLmodel = $0
            }
        }
    }

    var list: some View {
        List {
//            ForEach(viewModel.sections, id: \.self) { section in
                Section(header: Text(viewModel.sections[0])) {
                    ForEach(NBAmodel, id: \.id) { model in
                        Text(model.shortName)
                    }
                }
                Section(header: Text(viewModel.sections[1])) {
                    ForEach(NFLmodel, id: \.id) { model in
                        Text(model.shortName)
                        }
                    }
//            }
        }
        .onAppear{
            Api().NFLrequest{ (model) in
            self.NFLmodel = model
            }
            Api().NBArequest{ (model) in
            self.NBAmodel = model
            }
        }
    }
}

struct OrderingView: View {
    @State private var sections: [String]
    @State private var NBAmodel: [Event]
    @State private var NFLmodel: [Event]
    let callback: ([String]) -> ()
    let callbacks: ([Event]) -> ()

    init(sections: [String], section: [Event], callback: @escaping ([String]) -> (), callbacks: @escaping ([Event]) -> ())
    {
        self._sections = State(initialValue: sections)
        self._NBAmodel = State(initialValue: section)
        self._NFLmodel = State(initialValue: section)
        self.callback = callback
        self.callbacks = callbacks
    }

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                ForEach(sections, id: \.self) { section in
                    Text(section)
                }
                .onMove {
                    self.sections.move(fromOffsets: $0, toOffset: $1)
                    self.NBAmodel.move(fromOffsets: $0, toOffset: $1)
                    self.NFLmodel.move(fromOffsets: $0, toOffset: $1)
                }
            }
            .navigationBarItems(trailing: EditButton())
        }
        .onDisappear {
            self.callback(self.sections)
            self.callbacks(self.NBAmodel)
            self.callbacks(self.NFLmodel)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you create a [mre]? You've included types that we don't have access to, so it won't compile.

Comment: The link I attached it the basic use of it, my NBAmodel and NFLmodel is just codable data that is being displayed in list section

Comment: If it's simple, include it -- don't make people stub out your types and methods. You're also using `Api`, which we don't have access to. Make a [mre] so it's easier for people to help. It's still not a guarantee you'll get an answer, but there will be a *much* better chance.